# Strange `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil` but optional DOES have a value

Tags: swift, crash

I am experiencing a strange crash in my app while updating a `label.text` with a string from a variable that does have a value.

```
if WalletViewController.currencyUSD == true {
                MainViewController.bitcoinDoublePrice = Double((bitcoinInfo.raw.btc.usd?.price)!)
                print("MainViewController.bitcoinDoublePrice =", MainViewController.bitcoinDoublePrice)
                let formatter = NumberFormatter()
                formatter.numberStyle = .currency
                formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
                let bitcoinStringPrice = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: MainViewController.bitcoinDoublePrice))
                print("bitcoinStringPrice =", bitcoinStringPrice!)
                if let bitcoinPrice = bitcoinStringPrice {
                    MainViewController().bitcoinPriceLabel.text = String(bitcoinPrice + ", ") //<<<Thread 3: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
                } else {
                    print("bitcoinPrice = nil")
                }
            }
```

Some screenshots:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeBam.png)

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4wtr.png)

I can't figure out what's going on here

Comment: Some screenshots can tell a million words, but these are not one of them. Please include your code as text.

Comment: Which part do you need?

Comment: It's not a good idea to screenshot code, just copy and paste it into the question. That way people can duplicate what you are doing more easily.

Comment: @ColGraff Not only that, but the post will also have better searchability.

Comment: I edited the question with the code

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `bitcoinPriceLabel` value before it is being drawn.

It is not the value.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing **a new instance** of `MainViewController` in the line where the error occurs.

View controllers don't have their outlets installed directly after an initialization, so `bitcoinPriceLabel` will be nil.

Change `MainViewController()` to the instance of it you're currently using, so it will reference the label of the view controller that is visible in your application (in this example, `mainVc`):

```
mainVc.bitcoinPriceLabel.text = String(bitcoinPrice + ", ")
```

Learn more about the view controller lifecycle [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW3).

Comment: I can't remove `()` without getting `Instance member 'bitcoinPriceLabel' cannot be used on type 'MainViewController'`

Comment: My code is in another file because the function is too large to be in the 'MainViewController'

Comment: If that's the case, you should pass a reference of the used instance of MainViewController to the class this code is in. [Learn more about passing data between view controllers here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5210535/3151675)

Comment: Can't I just store the values in a static var and update the labels from the MainViewController? I am sorry but this method was working before I changed the way I fetch the data from the API so I am really struggling understanding what's wrong now.

Comment: Possibly.  Show the code for the definition of MainViewController as this affects how you access it.